# Comment/Uncomment multiple lines in JupyterNotebook hotkey

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I was wondering, if there is a PRO way of commenting/removing multiline # comments in JupyterNotebooks.

```
# line1
# line2
# line3
```

Something like **SHIFT + "** for adding triple quotes.

Comment: how about `CTRL + /` , that is, control and forward slash

Comment: Wow, it's that simple, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

CTRL+/ for comment and uncomment multiple lines
you can press 'h' anywhere in command mode, you can find all the shortcuts of jupyter.

Comment: CTRL+/ doesn't work for me...

Comment: Does not work in notebook 7.

Answer (score 5):

For the big bunch of people that does not use an english keyboard, probably the adequate keys are in other place.
In the case of a Spanish Keyboard, I can comment/uncomment lines using "Ctrl + }"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On a German keyboard layout I use `CMD` + `?` successfully.

Comment: For me it's Ctrl + #

Answer (score 1):

For those with a Portuguese keyboard and Windows operating system, `CTRL + ~` comments multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

For Portuguese keyboard is <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

[image: French keyboard]

On a french Keyboard use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

Comment: control + /  worked with Apple short keyboard on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

for me, German keyboard layout: `Ctrl + #` works

Answer (score 0):

simply we can use the control + / (back slash) button to we can comment multiple lines at a time.

Comment: `/` this is a forward slash. Also, please do not copy-paste answers from others, which is clearly plagiarism!

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute. You can show your support for an original answer by upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

Just switch to US keyboard while coding. You only need to know the keys by heart. Then, you can press the US shortcut `Ctrl`+`/` on this "US keyboard", it should be the next button left to the right `shift` button. Your country's keyboard will not play a role anymore.